# Listen if 2 events are dispatch

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to listen if 2 events are dispatch ?

Example :

When puzzle = true  --> `dispatchEvent(new Event("the first"));`

when puzzle2 = true --> `dispatchEvent(new Event("the second"));`

And then :

do something if "the first" is dispatch
do something if "the second" is dispatch

and do another thing if "the first" AND "the second" are dispatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event structure is completely independent of each other. One event can be dispatched just as easily as another.

```
puzzle.addEventListener("the first", handler1);
puzzle2.addEventListener("the second", handler2);
```

Alternatively, you could also have both events trigger the same function.

```
puzzle.addEventListener("the first", handler);
puzzle2.addEventListener("the second", handler);
```